# Display deflation percentage of tar command (like zip command)

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, zip, tar

This question may sound weird but I would like to know if there is a possibility to display the deflation percentage of the files processed in the `tar` command.

I use this command `tar -cjvf "$BACKUP_PATH/Complete Backup $date.tar.bz2" $MINECRAFT_PATH` to create a backup of a minecraft game server.
And this is displaying all the files it is processing. This looks almost like the `zip` command. The difference here is that once the `zip` command is finished it displays how much the file got deflated. I wonder if this is possible with the tar command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible, because the files are first archived (`tar`) then the result is compressed as a whole (`bz2` or `gz`). This is (edit: one of) the reasons why `tar.bz2` or `tar.gz` are usually smaller than `zip`, specially when they contain a lot of small and similar files.

Comment: That's not the only reason. You can't compare the compression ratio between bzip2, gzip and zip directly because each of them uses a different compression algorithm.

Comment: as far as I know gzip and zip algorithm are quite similar (based on DEFLATE) but you're right, I'll edit the answer

Comment: almost all Zip archives use the same DEFLATE as gzip – you can even use `gunzip` with them; APPNOTE.TXT also allows using bzip2 (and a few other algorithms).

Answer (score 2):

If you first run `tar` and then either `gzip` or `bzip2`, then you can pass both of these the option `-v` to show the compression ratio, e.g. like this:

```
tar -cvf - foo/ | bzip2 -v > foo.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

What for? You can tell to tar write to stdout number block is processed, or you can run command that get processed block number. this is base for percentage display. use option

```
tar ...something ... --checkpoint --checkpoint-action=ACTION
```

see man tar .